# How do I take two audio feeds and combine them into a single stream?

Tags: audio, skype, audio-recording

I have two locations where I am recording/broadcasting audio and I need to figure out a way to combine those audio feeds into a single audio stream.

Think of what I am trying to accomplish as doing a Skype Conference where two users/computers are having a conversation and there is one central point the audio is being recorded/streamed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Many of the podcasters I know that have hosts in different locations like to do what they call a "double ender". Both sides record the conversation then one person joins the two tracks in a multi-track editor (e.g. Audacity, Audition, Garageband). They edit for content and for the "drift" that tends to happen. The mutli-track editor can then export one file with all of the audio in it.

Another option would be to get a mixer and have all audio go through that first where everything gets joined together before hitting the recording device.

There are MANY how-to articles on both options. You just need to choose which will work best for you.

Comment: +1 for Audacity, I love it. Consider looking at Levelator as well as a simple one step way to really increase the general sound quality after it has all been edited and mixed http://www.conversationsnetwork.org/levelator